# Jpanel error repainting

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've created my own extended JPanel to able the user to sign on it, after that save the signature and delete from the panel:

```
public class PanelParaFirmar extends JPanel
{
private MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
private int index = 0;
private Point[] arr = new Point[100000];

    public PanelParaFirmar()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        this.paintComponents(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
            g.drawLine(arr[i].x, arr[i].y, arr[i + 1].x, arr[i + 1].y);
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
        index++;
        repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            arr = new Point[100000];
            index = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            //updateUI();
            //save();
            arr[index] = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            index++;
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    }

};
```

Before click on it all it's right:
[image]

But when I started to sign, it repaints the rootPane:
[image]

How can I paint just the line?

Comment: Try calling `super.paintComponent(g)` instead of `this.paintComponents(g)` (note , no _s_  at paintComponent) .

Comment: Thanks, but now, when when i release the mouse button it creates a new line in the next signature, some signatures have more than one line. and How can I delete all the lines?

Comment: Are you saying that you accept signatures having several lines ?

Comment: Yes, some times a signature need to make one line then "lift the pen" and make the second one

Comment: So your event for determining the end of a signature, shouldn't be the mouse release, but rather something like an action on a given button (e.g on your _GUARDAR_ button) .

Comment: Yes, but when i release the mouse i just want to not paint the line, and when i click again want to paint since the new point and ndon't delete the lines before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the fact that you should override `paintComponent` and not `paintComponents` , and call its `super` implementation, here is how you could manage multiple lines for one signature .

Create a list of *lines* ( a line is nothing else than a list of `Point`) to represent the signature.

When the mouse is pressed, add a new line to the list, and add the current point to this line.

When the mouse is dragged, add the current point to the current line.

Finally, your paint method will paint each line one after the other, without making junctions between them :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelParaFirmar extends JPanel {
    private final MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();

    private final List<List<Point>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Point> currentLine;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setSize(400, 200);
        fr.getContentPane().add(new PanelParaFirmar());
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public PanelParaFirmar() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (List<Point> line : lines) {

            for (int i = 0; i < line.size() - 1; i++) {

                Point thisPoint = line.get(i);
                Point nextPoint = line.get(i + 1);

                g.drawLine(thisPoint.x, thisPoint.y, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);

            }
        }

    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {

            currentLine = new ArrayList<Point>();
            currentLine.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));

            lines.add(currentLine);

            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {

            Point p = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
            currentLine.add(p);
            repaint();
        }


    }

}
```

Also note that since you are using a `MouseAdapter` , you don't have to implement the methods you don't need (like `mouseClicked`).

Comment: Thanks! Now i need to have a method to delete all lines. When one person signed on it then i will blank all the content and allow the user to sign again.

Comment: Just add a method that does `lines = new ArrayList<>()` then `repaint();`.